# Extending Kuali Document Business Object

Tags: ojb, kuali

I am facing an issue with extended attributes on a document (trying to extend a document table).  I created the original table’s PK (FDOC_NBR) in the extended table and linked the two via a foreignKey of the customized original table’s ojb entry (as an “extension” reference-descriptor). I created the bo and dd for the extension and customized the original document’s dd to add the new attributes. On the extended BO itself I also added members (with setters and getters) for the 2 new columns + for the PK column of documentNumber. I also added the new attributes to the documet’s jsp.  The pertinent module definition was already extended to include custom dd, ojb, etc. files.

Indeed, when opening the document the new fields are shown- however, when trying to submit the document (regardless of doing anything with the new fields) I get an error-

> Error Details: OJB operation; SQL []; ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL
>   into ("KFSTEM"."TEM_TRVL_ARRANGER_DOC_EXT_T"."FDOC_NBR") ; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("KFSTEM"."TEM_TRVL_ARRANGER_DOC_EXT_T"."FDOC_NBR")

Seems like somehow the system tries to insert a value of NULL into the extension’s PK field, instead of the actual document number. Trying to debug this, in the action’s route method and all the way down to DocumentDaoOjb.save (which is as far down as I can go) I see the document with the real doc number is passed on, so the problem seems to be purely with ojb trying to set this number to the extension table.

Does anyone have any experience with extended attributes on documents that could help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KFS is using the KNS, and in the Kuali Nervous System, the primary key on the extended attributes object must be set through manual intervention.

In this case, it looks as if you're adding an extended attribute to a transactional document, the Travel Arranger document (TAA), which simplifies things.  Basically, you'll need to extend org.kuali.kfs.module.tem.document.TravelArrangerDocument and override prepareForSave to set the document number there (it may be set already since prepareForSave should be called several times during the routing process, but there's no real harm from overwriting that information as the base document's number will remain the same).

Hope this helps!